# Providing initial data for models - Django

Tags: django, django-models

I want to enter default values in Django Models. For example, I have created one `Role` Model

```
class Role(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('role')
        verbose_name_plural = _('roles')
        db_table = "role"

    def __str__(self) : 
        return self.name
```

I want to enter default values whenever I am migrating - `makemigrations` and `migrate`.

**Example data should be entered -**

```
name - Super Admin
Description - This is Super Admin
name - Admin
Description - This is Admin
name - Manager
Description - This is Manager
```

This will help reduce the amount of manual work I need to perform.. Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/initial-data/)? It suggests two ways to populate your db with initial data. I usually go with [data migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/migrations/#data-migrations)

Comment: @dirkgroten i found the way to do it. see the answer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found a good way to do it. First we create a `JSON` file using the below line. Note - `role` is the app's name.

```
python3 manage.py dumpdata --format=json role > initial_role_data.json
```

After running the above commands it will create a file named `initial_role_data.json` which will have data something like this:

```
[
   {
      "model":"role.role",
      "pk":1,
      "fields":{
         "name":"Super Admin",
         "description":"This is Super Admin"
      }
   },
   {
      "model":"role.role",
      "pk":2,
      "fields":{
         "name":"Admin",
         "description":"This is Admin"
      }
   },
]
```

**Note I have data already inside my `database table`. You can create a json file similar to above manually if needed.**

Once the `json` file is generated we will load the data:

```
python3 manage.py loaddata initial_role_data.json
```